# Best Way to Validate Access Token?

Tags: sonos

I'm looking to implement services where the client will pass the access_token from Sonos to the service I host.*  Is there a good way to validate that  access_token from the client is valid and get the user id? For reference, I'm thinking of something similar to googleapis.auth.OAuth2.verifyIdToken.

Thanks!

- The driver of this is wanting to fully delegate authorization and authentication to Sonos. I want to have an Alexa skill which just auths with Sonos and don't want to 'build out' the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear about what you're trying to do, and I'm a little concerned that it runs afoul of [sect 10.3 of the OAuth 2.0 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-25#section-10.3), but validating a token should be as simple as performing a simple GET /households.

Comment: Got it. I ended up issuing my own access token, so validation would be faster and more reliable than calling an external service. Would be great if the access tokens from Sonos were JSON web tokens signed RSA so that the public key could be shared to validate it.